# Sort an Array by Identifying the numeric value for each element through charCodeAt() method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code that I've thus far to sort an array by the charCodeAt() method. Can someone help me identify what is incorrect?

```
var sortByCharCodeAt = function(array){
  array.sort((a, b) => a.charCodeAt - b.charCodeAt)
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    array.sort((a, b) => {
      a.charCodeAt(i) - b.charCodeAt(i)
    })
  }
  console.log(array);
}

sortByCharCodeAt(["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]);
```

Comment: What is the expected and actual behavior?

Comment: Are all the strings in the array 1 letter long?

Answer (score 3):

You have to return the result in sort method

```
array.sort((a, b) => {
  // You didn't return the result here
  return a.charCodeAt(i) - b.charCodeAt(i)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert them into an array of charcodes then sort it, then convert it back to character

```js
var sortByCharCodeAt = function(array){
  //to emphasize the process
  let newArray= array.map((entry)=>{return entry.charCodeAt(0)})
  newArray.sort()
  newArray= newArray.map((entry)=>{return String.fromCharCode(entry)})
  
  console.log(newArray);
  
  //simplified version
   console.log(array.sort((a, b) => a.charCodeAt(0) - b.charCodeAt(0)))
}

sortByCharCodeAt(["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]);
```